# Using echo to print variable string not showing anything

Tags: php, string, url

I am creating this string:

```
$s = '<http://example.org/data/'.$q.'>';
```

where `$q` is a request parameter. The problem is what when I echo or `print_r` it I get nothing as a result. Also when I use `var_dump` I only get `string(34)` as a result. I have used several methods such as:

```
$s = "<http://example.org/data/$q>";
```

or

```
$s = "<http://example.org/data/" . $q . ">";
```

But I get the same result. The same problem occurs when i echo this `string`:

```
$query = "PREFIX sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/data/> PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
SELECT ?o WHERE {" . $s . "geo:isLocationOf ?o}";
```

where I get:

```
PREFIX sosa: PREFIX ex: PREFIX geo: SELECT ?o WHERE {geo:isLocationOf ?o}
```

There seems to be a problem with using urls in `strings`.

Comment: show us the full code with ```$q```

Comment: If your viewing this in a browser - view the source as it may be interpreting it as HTML tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `echo htmlspecialchars($s);`

Convert the predefined characters

> "<" (less than) and ">" (greater than)

to HTML entities via `htmlspecialchars` function.

For more check w3c[htmlspecialchars](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. Hope it helps.

```
$q = "test-message";
$s = htmlspecialchars("< http://www.google.com/". $q ."> ");
$query = "PREFIX sosa: < http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> PREFIX ex: < http://example.org/data/> PREFIX geo: < http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> SELECT ?o WHERE {" . $s . "geo:isLocationOf ?o}";
echo $query;
```